# Add woocommerce.css in template?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Why  file `plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css` 
for my template can not be read?

Please look this image :

[image]

Comment: If for some reason ur theme can't read `woocommerce.css` Then try to manually call that file like `<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css" rel="stylesheet">`. And if u r using child them then use `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` instead of `bloginfo('template_directory')` to call `woocommerce.css`.

Comment: thank you , but is not loading again :/

Comment: Questions specific to WooCommerce are off-topic here, and are better asked about at WooCommerce's own forum.

Comment: @Tim Malone May be the question is related to wordpress only! He is asking why my wordpress is not picking a css file. And that file is css file or any other file, And that file is in plugin folder or in theme folder or where ever! does that matter!?

Answer (score 1):

```
function woocommmerce_style() {
   wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_stylesheet', WP_PLUGIN_URL. '/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css',false,'1.0',"all");
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'woocommmerce_style' );
```

paste the above code in your "functions.php". woocommerce stylesheet will be executed to your site

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42039/discussion-on-answer-by-pullata-praveen-add-woocommerce-css-in-template).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I added "woocommerce woocommerce-page" classes to body, or parents of woocommerce loop, so it solved the problem,

actually, woocommerce main classes are not add to page.

Answer (score 0):

As @ali-h correctly points out, the missing body classes are the culprit here...

You can solve this by using the corresponding filter `body_class` and add your own classes, in this case the WooCommerce-specific ones:

```
/**
 * Add <body> classes
 */
add_filter('body_class', function (array $classes) {
  /** Add WC classes if on a custom template or when viewing search results */
  if (is_page_template('directory-name/page-something.php') || is_search()) {
    $classes[] = 'woocommerce woocommerce-page';
  }

  return array_filter($classes);
});
```